# Oracle Ingest entire directory/file attributes into an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have large number of batch jobs which generate ascii log files. We browse these logs using commands/tools such as GREP or VI/VIM editors.

Simple text searches are fine. But if we have to search these log files for a particular string and compare date/times when the string was generated - the task become unwieldy. It means finding the file which has the string and manually noting down modification date/time of the file.

Are there any tools which can ingest an entire directory structure on linux and store it into an Oracle table with following attributes:

```
1. Full name of directory
2. Filename
3. File Modification Date/time
4. Line number
5. Line Text
```

Comment: Yes. An external table with a pre-processor shell script. [Find out more](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513)